# How to skip authorization for HAL browser in a spring boot application that make use of spring security

Tags: spring-security-rest

I wanted to allow HAL browser to skip authorization on a spring boot application. I am using Spring Security for authorization.

Here is the snap shot of the entries from build.gradle file

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

My Spring boot application runs on port 2128

http://localhost:2128/browser/index.html would open the HAL browser before spring security was implemented.
I tried adding                        **.antMatchers("/browser/index.html**").permitAll()** in the configure method of SecurityConfiguration class given below. I also tried overriding **public void configure(WebSecurity web)** method to ignore the URL

**Background** : *HAL Browser was working before I have implemented Spring Security Authorization. It stopped working after spring security was implemented.*

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                        .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userRepository))
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        // configure access rules
                        .antMatchers("/browser/index.html**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();

                http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
                web.ignoring().antMatchers("/browser/index.html");
            }

        }
```

```
        public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

            public static final String HEADER_STRING_REMOTE_USER = "Remote-User";

            /**
             * Security pipe line is composed of different filters so we need to delegate to the rest of the pipeline.
             *
             * @param request
             * @param response
             * @param chain
             * @throws IOException
             * @throws ServletException
             */
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

                // Read the Authorization header, where we get the userId
                String userId = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING_REMOTE_USER);

                // If header does not contain userId or is null delegate to Spring impl and exit
                if (userId == null) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                }

                // If userId is present, try grab user principal from database and perform authorization
                Authentication authentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(userId);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

                // Continue filter execution
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }

            private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication (String userId) {

                // Search in the DB if we find the user by userId
                // If so, then grab user details and create spring auth token using username, pass, authorities/roles
                if (userId != null) {
                    List user = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
                    UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(user.get(0));
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, principal.getAuthorities());
                    return auth;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Has anybody experienced similar issues...

Comment: Have you tried `.antMatchers("/browser/**").permitAll()` ?. 
There are more resources needed besides the index.html (js, css, images). 
Of course, for your api calls you will need auth, so you either need to have a session cookie, or you can specify the Authorization header in hal-explorer if you use it.

PS: if you are using the new hal-explorer instead of hal-browser, use `.antMatchers("/explorer/**").permitAll()`

Comment: Yes I have tried that at the first place. It created problems with the Firewalled request generated from security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is to manage using spring active profiles.

For more information on spring profiles see the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

I enabled Spring Security for "secure" profile and disabled it for "dev" profile. So in "dev" profile HAL browser works without any security interruptions.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("secure")
public class WebSecurityConfigEnable extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

        public WebSecurityConfigEnable (UserPrincipalDetailsService 
userPrincipalDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> new 
CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
               .csrf().disable()

.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), 
userRepository, activeProfile))
                .authorizeRequests()
                // configure access rules
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider () {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userPrincipalDetailsService);

    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder () {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

For running the application in "dev" profile

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev build\libs\springApp-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: But is the best way??

Comment: This is just work-around.